# Conditionally Output List Value in Python Function

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, iteration, conditional-statements

I am making a simple console game and I need a function which displays the board differently depending on the state of the board and the arguments it receives.

The board is a 2d list, which either has a value which is meaningful to the game, or an `EMPTY_SPOT`.

How can I modify my function so that it checks in the nested loop whether the current position is in the `visible` argument, and if so displays the value of the list at that position please? The tuples represent `(row, column)`.

I've already adjusted my loop to use `range` instead of `for item in...` as I expect I will need those `i,j` values.

```
 def display_cards(board, visible=[(0, 2), (1, 0)]):
        print(visible)
        for i in range(4):
            for j in range(4):
                if board[i][j] == EMPTY_SPOT:
                    print(EMPTY_SPOT)
                else:
                    print(HIDDEN_CARD, end=EMPTY_SPOT)
            print()
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the code you’ve shown?

Comment: It doesn't implement the desired functionality as described.

Comment: Why did you think it would? The visible list isn't used at all in the actual logic.

Comment: I know - hence "How can I modify my function so that it checks in the nested loop whether the current position is in the visible argument, and if so displays the value of the list at that position please? The tuples represent (row, column)."

Comment: SO is neither a code-writing or tutorial service; there's a useful collection of more appropriate resources here: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def display_cards(board, visible):
    print(visible) # Assume visible is {(0, 2), (1, 0)}
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            if (i, j) in visible:
               # The current position is in visible...

            if board[i][j] == EMPTY_SPOT:
                print(EMPTY_SPOT)
            else:
                print(HIDDEN_CARD, end=EMPTY_SPOT)
        print()
```

You can check whether the coordinate tuple is `in` the `visible` collection. Also avoid setting mutable objects as default parameter values since the behavior can be [a bit unexpected](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments).

Comment: No, the behavior will not be unexpected, as it do not modify the mutable object inside the function.

Comment: Right, but if someone comes along later and does modify it, then that might be a problem. Just a general suggestion but you're right, as is this will not cause any issues.

Comment: Not a problem here as well. As the other one should know this behavior as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `in` keyword to check if co-ordinate are in visible.

```py
def display_cards(board, visible={(0, 2), (1, 0)}): 
    print(visible) 
    for i in range(4): 
        for j in range(4): 
            if (i, j) in visible: 
                print(board[i][j])
            elif board[i][j] == EMPTY_SPOT: 
                print(EMPTY_SPOT) 
            else: 
                print(HIDDEN_CARD, end=EMPTY_SPOT) 
          print()
```

## Note

- Use a set instead of list for visible, the lookup will be faster
- You could generate a generator and then print it, it will be faster and cleaner.

```py
def display_cards_evaluation(board, visible={(0, 2), (1, 0)}): 
    print(visible) 
    for i in range(4): 
        for j in range(4): 
            if (i, j) in visible: 
                yield board[i][j]
            elif board[i][j] == EMPTY_SPOT: 
                yield EMPTY_SPOT
            else: 
                yield HIDDEN_CARD, end=EMPTY_SPOT

def display_cards(evaluation):
    for element in evaluation:
        print(element)

display_cards(display_cards_evaluation(board))
```

Comment: +1 to using a set, but how will using a generator be faster? Seems like the bottleneck would be multiple calls to `print`.